# Sqlalchemy automatically deletes objects in list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm writing simple app using FastAPI and SqlAlchemy. I have written function to get a list
of users:

```py
async def get_users(
            db: sqlalchemy.ext.AsyncSession,
            start_id: int = ...,
            end_id: int = ...,
        ):
    return await db.execute(sql.select(models.User).offset(start_id).limit(
        abs(end_id - start_id) + 1
    ))
```

And an endpoint which uses this function:

```py
@router.get('/')
async def get_users(
            page: int = 1,
            page_size: int = 20,
            db: asyncio.AsyncSession = fastapi.Depends(crud.get_session),
        ):
    users = await crud.get_users(
        db, 
        start_id=((page - 1) * page_size), 
        end_id=((page - 1) * page_size)
    )
    
    for user in users:
        print(user)
    print('!')

    for user in users:
        print(user)
    print('!')

    print({
        'error': False,
        'page': 1,
        'page_size': 20,
        'users': [{
            'id': user.id,
            'email': user.email,
            'is_banned': user.is_banned,
            'balance': 0,
        } for user in users],
    }

    ...
)
```

The output:

```
(<models.User object at 0x7f152fa3b760>,)
!
!
{'error': False, 'page': 1, 'page_size': 20, 'users': []}
```

Why does sqlalchemy deletes users from list? How to disable this?

Comment: The `get_users` function is returning an iterator. Return `db.execute(...).all()` to return a list that can be iterated over repeatedly.